# Javascript FileReader sometimes don't work

Tags: javascript, html, input, filereader

I'm building an application to create TextureAtlas that can be used in DartFlash.
My idea is to load many files using the input tag, and then using the FileReader API transform these files in images, draw them on a canvas and dump the canvas as an image which the user can download, along a JSON file describing the image.
However it sometimes fails to accomplish the task and write the output image properly.
I'm pretty sure that this is a sync problem, but I can't find were is the issue.
I have tested it in Chrome, where it succeed more often. In Firefox it has a higher failure rate.

Here is the code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 "use strict"

 var files=null;
 var img_list=[];
 var num_files=-1;
 var img_list_length=0;
 var output_json={}
 var output_canvas=null;
 var output_img=null;
 var download_png=null;

 function createOutputImg()
 {
    if(num_files != img_list_length)
    {
        return;
    }
    img_list.sort(function (a,b)
    {
        if(a.name > b.name)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    });
    output_canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
    var total_width=0;
    var highest_height=0;
    for (var i=0; i<img_list.length; i++)
    {
        total_width+=img_list[i].width;
        if(highest_height < img_list[i].height)
        {
            highest_height=img_list[i].height;
        }
    }
    console.log(total_width);
    output_canvas.width=total_width;
    output_canvas.height=highest_height;
    var context=output_canvas.getContext("2d");
    output_json["frames"]=[];
    var current_posx=0;
    for (var i=0; i<img_list.length; i++)
    {
        var img=img_list[i];
        context.drawImage(img, current_posx, 0);
        console.log(i.toString()+" - "+img.name);
        output_json["frames"].push(
        {
            "filename":img.name,
            "frame":
            {
                "x":current_posx,
                "y":0,
                "w":img.width,
                "h":img.height
            },
            "rotated":false,
            "trimmed":false,
            "spriteSourceSize":
            {
                "x":0,
                "y":0,
                "w":img.width,
                "h":img.height
            },
            "sourceSize":
            {
                "w":img.width,
                "h":img.height
            }
        });
        current_posx+=img.width;
    }
    output_img=document.createElement('img');
    output_img.src=output_canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    if(output_img.width != total_width)
    {
        alert("Error happened somewhere, please, refresh and retry again");
        return;
    }

    var paragraph=document.createElement('p');
    paragraph.innerHTML="Type a name for this resource.";
    document.body.appendChild(paragraph);

    var input_name=document.createElement('input');
    input_name.type="text";
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    document.body.appendChild(input_name);
    var go_button=document.createElement('button');
    go_button.innerHTML="Download";
    document.body.appendChild(go_button);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    go_button.inputElement=input_name;
    go_button.onclick=function (evt)
    {
        var resource_name=evt.target.inputElement.value;
        if(resource_name == "")
        {
            alert ("Please type a name for this resource.");
            return;
        }
        output_json["meta"]={}
        output_json["meta"]["app"]="HTML ImagePacker";
        output_json["meta"]["image"]=resource_name+".png";
        output_json["meta"]["format"]="RGBA8888";
        output_json["meta"]["size"]={};
        output_json["meta"]["size"]["w"]=output_img.width;
        output_json["meta"]["size"]["h"]=output_img.height;
        output_json["meta"]["scale"]="1";
        var json_data=new Blob([JSON.stringify(output_json)]);
        var download_json=document.createElement('a');
        download_json.innerHTML=resource_name+".json";
        download_json.download=download_json.innerHTML;
        download_json.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(json_data);
        var download_png=document.createElement('a');
        download_png.innerHTML=resource_name+".png";
        download_png.download=download_png.innerHTML;
        download_png.href=output_img.src;
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        document.body.appendChild(download_json);
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        document.body.appendChild(download_png);
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        document.body.appendChild(output_img);
    };
 }

 function handleFileSelect()
 {
    var files=document.getElementById("files").files;
    num_files=files.length;
    console.log(files);
    var height=0;
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++)
    {
        (function (file)
        {
            var reader=new FileReader();
            reader.name=file.name;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload=(function (evt) 
            {
                //console.log(evt);
                if(evt.target.readyState == 2)
                {
                    var img=document.createElement('img');
                    img.name=evt.target.name;
                    img.src=evt.target.result;
                    img_list.push(img);
                    img_list_length+=1;
                    //document.body.appendChild(img, null);
                    if(num_files == img_list_length)
                    {
                        createOutputImg();
                    }
                }
            });
        })(files[i]);
    }
 }

 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" onchange="handleFileSelect()"  multiple/><br>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You really should be declaring your local variables ("files", "height", "i", "reader", etc) with `var`.  Add the line `"use strict";` to the top of your code and you'll be told about several problems.

Comment: I had just made some modifications that the `"use strict"` had showed me, but it's still randomly failing in Firefox. However, it seems to be working on Google Chrome. Thanks for your suggestion. I really never knew that there were this `"use strict"` tag in javascript.